# how to Inject a Sentry 2 User Model into a controller - laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, ioc-container, cartalyst-sentry

How do you inject a Sentry 2 User model into a laravel 4 controller using IoC?

for example i would like the following

```
class myController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * creates a list of MyModel Models
     *
     * @return View
     */
    public function getIndex( User $user )
    {
        // fetch models
        $models = MyModel::all();

        // Show the page
        return View::make('my-views.the-view', compact('models', 'user'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I like to do it:

```
class myController extends BaseController {

    $protected $user

    /**
     * creates a list of MyModel Models
     *
     * @return View
     */

    function __construct(User $user){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getIndex()
    {
        // fetch models
        $models = MyModel::all();

        // Show the page
        return View::make('my-views.the-view', compact('models', 'user'));
    }

}
```

You can also do it in the method, but... well, give this a good read, too: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: This is great.. although i have realised that this returns the actual Sentry User model not the Sentry Provider Model so we would need to do the following:

`App::instance( 'User', Sentry::GetUser() );`

Comment: ALSO... to save having `compact('models', 'user')` in each view call. We could instead place `View::share('user', $user);` in the base controller constructor.

Comment: also you may be able to help me answer this question... as you seem in the IoC know how :-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445615/route-model-binding-and-soft-deletes-laravel-4

Comment: You got it - You do App::instance('foo', $foo); to "store" it, and then App::make('foo') to get it back out.  In addition to View::share(), check out http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers